# Team Foundation Server 2010 & SharePoint 2010 Upgrade

Tags: sharepoint-2010, tfs

I am very new to TFS and SharePoint so I hope I can explain myself as best as possible.
We currently run a single server farm that runs on Windows 2007 Standard, SQL 2008, TFS 2010 and SharePoint 3.0. I have been given the fun task of upgrading this to TFS 2012 and SharePoint 2010!

Now I have been following the steps that Microsoft provide but I am still hitting problems along the way and need to know the best possible approach!

I have built a new server with all TFS & SharePoint requirements. Windows 2008 R2, SQL 2008 R2. I have also installed TFS and SharePoint 2010. Before I configure anything I then used TFS backup and restore tools provided with the new installation to back up the existing Database on the old server and restored the databases onto the new server running SQL 2008 R2.

Before backing up the databases I made sure I have a backup of the report server encryption key. When trying to restore this I have the following problem?

> Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WMIProviderException: The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. A connection to the database is required for all requests and processing. (rsReportServerDatabaseUnavailable)

Have I missed any steps for the upgrade?

Also when performing this upgrade, is there any chance of this interrupting our current TFS & SharePoint production server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you selected "Install but do not configure" when installing Reporting Services. For TFS 2010+ you need to have it configured as the TFS install will not do that for you like it used to in 2005/2008.

I have a blog post that includes how to configure RS: http://nakedalm.com/integrate-reporting-and-analyses-services-with-team-foundation-server-2013/

Although this is for 2013 it applies equally to 2012.